# How to make the pointer focus on select in listview

Tags: android, listview

I use ListVew to show several items.
I use the code to list item.

```
getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, FileName, Check);
setListAdapter(MyAdapter);
```

And while item click, I use below code to refresh.

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, FileName, Check);
setListAdapter(MyAdapter);
```

FileName and Check are arrays.
But while I click one item, it refresh and the cursor return to top.
After refresh, I want it focus on the clicked one.
How to do it?

MyAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewTag viewTag;
if(convertView == null) {
convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_phone_video, null);
viewTag = new ViewTag(
(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_video_name),
(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone_video_check)                    
);
convertView.setTag(viewTag);
}
else {
viewTag = (ViewTag) convertView.getTag();
}

viewTag.title.setText(FileName[position]);
viewTag.cbx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if(Check[position]) {
viewTag.cbx.setChecked(true);
}
else {
viewTag.cbx.setChecked(false);
}
}
return convertView;
}

class ViewTag {
TextView title;
CheckBox cbx;
public ViewTag(TextView tv, CheckBox cb) {
this.title = tv;
this.cbx = cb;
}
}
```

Comment: I think it would be useful if you post the code for MyAdapter, and more of the ListView class including declarations of FileName and Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive)

This code will work if the user clicks the check box. Inside the getView function instead of checkbox click copy paste the code into converview's onclick listener.

Comment: But why I try notifyDataSetChanged(), it does not refresh?

Comment: When item click, I just set Check[i] false to true or true to false.

Comment: Sorry I dint get you properly. You have a listview with checkbox? You are updating the corresponding listitem's checkbox when the user clicks on the listitem? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I want to click item to select, but not only click the checkbox. So I do this.

Comment: Edited the answer. Request you to edit your question to make users understand it properly.